# Background of choosing standard for of a linear program as type III inequalities?

Tags: geometry, linear-programming

In linear programming where we seek to minimize $c^Tx \to \text{min}_{x\in P}!$
with respect to some inequality constraints, 
**why do we choose $P$ in the form**

> $Ax \leq b$, $x \geq 0$

**as the *standard form* of a linear program?**
In the geometrical view $\{x: Ax \leq b\}$ seems much more natural, why don't we use this, or a type II-inequality constraint?
(I am aware that we can transform the inequalities, but this does not always preserve the dimension of the problem, and gives an overhead to the proofs)

Comment: Exactly who "chooses $P$ in the form $Ax\le b,x\ge 0$"? I for one always use the _standard_ form $\min c^T x: Ax=b, x\ge 0$ as this is the formulation on which I can show the procession of the simplex method to my students most naturally. By the way, I think what you refer to is the _canonical_ form.